# Throwing Exception Troubles

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, data-structures, computer-science

I am difficulties with throwing the IllegalStateForMatrixException. If anyone could help me that would be greatly appreciated. This is what my professor told me to do, but I still am having problems actually doing it. Here is what he gave me as a tip...

IllegalStateForMatrixException should be raised when calling getNumberOfEdges with 0 edges. 
IllegalStateForMatrix should be raised when calling getNumberOfEdges with 0 edges.
All you need to do is check the matrix has no positive values. If it doesn't throw the IllegalStateForMatrix Exception.

You can also set a boolean value to false and when you call createMatrix set it true. This will be a way to check if createMatrix was called before or after addEdge. Then checking in addEdge you can throw the exception.

```
class AdjacencyGraph extends Graph {

private ArrayList nodes = new ArrayList();
private int noEdges = 0;

/**
 * Adjacency matrix.
 */
public int[][] adjM;

/**
 * Boolean set to false, should be set true in create matrix.
 */
private boolean b = false;

/**
 * Adjacency Matrix with integers.
 */
@Override
void createAdjacencyMatrix() {
    adjM = new int[nodes.size()][nodes.size()];
    int i;
    int j;
    for (i = 0; i < nodes.size(); i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < nodes.size(); j++) {
            adjM[i][j] = -1;
        }
        b = true;
    }
}

/**
 * Adds the node.
 *
 * @param nodeName
 */
@Override
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
void addNode(String nodeName) {
    nodes.add(nodeName);
}

/**
 * Adds the edge.
 *
 * @param fromNode
 * @param toNode
 * @param weight
 * @throws ElementNotFoundException
 * @throws IllegalStateForMatrixException
 */
@Override
void addEdge(String fromNode, String toNode, int weight)
        throws ElementNotFoundException, IllegalStateForMatrixException {
    {
        try {
            if ( b == false)
                throw new IllegalStateForMatrixException("Exception");
            int i;
            int j;
            for (i = 0; i < nodes.size(); i++) {
                if (nodes.get(i).equals(fromNode)) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (i == nodes.size()) {
                throw new ElementNotFoundException("Exception");
            }

            for (j = 0; j < nodes.size(); j++) {
                if (nodes.get(j).equals(toNode)) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (j == nodes.size()) {
                throw new ElementNotFoundException("Exception");
            }

            adjM[i][j] = weight;
            adjM[j][i] = weight;
            noEdges++;
        } 
        catch (ElementNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception found");
        }
        catch (IllegalStateForMatrixException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception found");
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Returns the number of nodes.
 *
 * @return number of nodes
 */
@Override
int getNumberOfNodes() {
    return nodes.size();
}

/**
 * Returns the number of edges
 *
 * @return number of edges
 * @throws IllegalStateForMatrixException
 */
@Override
int getNumberOfEdges() throws IllegalStateForMatrixException {
    if (nodes.size() <= 0)
        throw new IllegalStateForMatrixException("Error");
    return noEdges;
}

/**
 * Returns the highest degree node.
 *
 * @return highest degree node.
 * @throws ElementNotFoundException
 * @throws IllegalStateForMatrixException
 */
@Override
public String getHighestDegreeNode()
        throws ElementNotFoundException, IllegalStateForMatrixException {

    int i;
    int ansIndex = 0;
    int j;
    int ansCount = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < nodes.size(); i++) {
        int k = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < nodes.size(); j++) {
            if (adjM[i][j] != -1) {
                k++;
            }
        }
        if (k > ansCount) {
            ansCount = k;
            ansIndex = i;
        }
    }
    return (String) nodes.get(ansIndex);
}

/**
 * Cost of the edge between nodes.
 *
 * @param fromNode
 * @param toNode
 * @return returns -1
 * @throws ElementNotFoundException
 * @throws IllegalStateForMatrixException
 */
@Override
int costOfEdgeBetween(String fromNode, String toNode)
        throws ElementNotFoundException, IllegalStateForMatrixException {
    try {
        int i;
        int j;
        for (i = 0; i < nodes.size(); i++) {
            if (nodes.get(i).equals(fromNode)) {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (i == nodes.size()) {
            throw new ElementNotFoundException("Exception");
        }

        for (j = 0; j < nodes.size(); j++) {
            if (nodes.get(j).equals(toNode)) {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (j == nodes.size()) {
            throw new ElementNotFoundException("Exception");
        }

        return adjM[i][j];
    } 
    catch (ElementNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Exception found");
    }
    return -1;
}

/**
 *
 * @param fromName
 * @param toName
 * @return false
 * @throws ElementNotFoundException
 * @throws IllegalStateForMatrixException
 */
@Override
boolean hasPathBetween(String fromName, String toName)
        throws ElementNotFoundException, IllegalStateForMatrixException {
    try {
        ArrayStack<Integer> st = new ArrayStack<Integer>();
        int[] visited = new int[nodes.size()];
        int i;
        int j;
        int start;
        int end;
        for (i = 0; i < nodes.size(); i++) {
            visited[i] = 0;
        }

        for (i = 0; i < nodes.size(); i++) {
            if (nodes.get(i).equals(fromName)) {
                break;
            }
        }
        start = i;

        for (j = 0; j < nodes.size(); j++) {
            if (nodes.get(j).equals(toName)) {
                break;
            }
        }
        end = j;
        st.push(start);
        visited[start] = 1;
        while (st.isEmpty() != true) {
            i = st.pop();
            if (i == end) {
                return true;
            }
            for (j = 0; j < nodes.size(); j++) {
                if (adjM[i][j] != -1 && visited[j] == 0) {
                    visited[j] = 1;
                    st.push(j);
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception found");
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * The number of Isolated points
 *
 * @return ans
 * @throws IllegalStateForMatrixException
 */
@Override
int numIsolatedPoints() throws IllegalStateForMatrixException {
    int i;
    int j;
    int ans = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < nodes.size(); i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < nodes.size(); j++) {
            if (adjM[i][j] != -1) {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (j == nodes.size()) {
            ans++;
        }
    }
    return ans;
}

/**
 * Inclusiveness is the percentage of points in the graph that are not
 * isolated
 *
 * @return ((float)i)/nodes.size()
 * @throws IllegalStateForMatrixException
 */
@Override
float inclusiveness() throws IllegalStateForMatrixException {
    int i = nodes.size() - numIsolatedPoints();
    return ((float) i) / nodes.size();
}

/**
 * Density of matrix
 *
 * @return (2*(float)noEdges)/(nodes.size()*(nodes.size()-1))
 * @throws IllegalStateForMatrixException
 */
@Override
float density() throws IllegalStateForMatrixException {
    return (2 * (float) noEdges) / (nodes.size() * (nodes.size() - 1));
}

/**
 * Print out the adjacency matrix
 */
void print() {
    System.out.println(adjM);
}
```

}

Comment: You are catching the exceptions before they can exit your method. Or what is your actual problem?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  A few suggestions,  read [ask], post a [mcve], and explain what " having problems" means.  Thanks

Comment: whats your problem dude? what isnt working the way u want it to?

Comment: How do I throw and catch the IllegalStateForMatrix properly. Where would I properly catch the exception?

Answer (score 0):

> How do I throw and catch the IllegalStateForMatrix properly. Where
>   would I properly catch the exception? –

Here `IllegalStateForMatrixException` conveys that an operation was invoked on the object while the object is not in a state with the required pre-condition to accept this operation.

You want get a number of edges but you have no matrix ?
It makes no sense.

It is an important problem, so you have to raise the exception **until the caller of the method that has provoked the exception rising**.

Besides thes methods declare throwing `IllegalStateForMatrixException`.
So if the exception is checked (not a child of RuntimeException), the client has to handle it.

In your code, two methods throw the exception.
Here you do the things good :

```
@Override
int getNumberOfEdges() throws IllegalStateForMatrixException {
    if (nodes.size() <= 0)
        throw new IllegalStateForMatrixException("Error");
    return noEdges;
}
```

You throw the exception to the client that has to handle it.

Bu there :

```
void addEdge(String fromNode, String toNode, int weight)
        throws ElementNotFoundException, IllegalStateForMatrixException {        
   try {
        if ( b == false)
           throw new IllegalStateForMatrixException("Exception");
        }
       ...
      }
    catch (IllegalStateForMatrixException e) {
       System.out.println("Exception found");
    }
       ...
}
```

You don't allow the exception to be propagated to the caller as you rise it in the method but you also catch it in.
As in the first case, you don't need to have a try/catch statement.

Comment: Would I get rid of the try catch for the ElementNotFoundException as well then? Just throw them without a catch... thanks for the help btw.

Comment: You are welcome :) It is the same thing that for IllegalStateForMatrixException. Which is the sense of explicitly throwing ElementNotFoundException if you catch it in the same place where you have risen it ?